Can't find unit "System.Diagnostics" in TMS WEB Core
I'm trying to use TStopwatch from the System.Diagnostics unit, but it's not finding it. I'm getting the following error:

[Error] can't find unit "System.Diagnostics"

I know most of the common Delphi units either work out of the box in TMS WEB Core or have a wrapper unit for it.
What about System.Diagnostics and TStopwatch? Is there a TMS WEB Core version of this?

I tried searching for "TMS WEB Core System.Diagnostics" and "TMS WEB Core TStopwatch" on Google and Bing, but couldn't find anything.

Please stop adding the tag information to the question title. The tag system works very well here, and SO has worked with Google to make sure they're included for SEO. The TMS Web Core is fine for this question, because it clarifies the System.Diagnostics issue, but the (Delphi) is noise. For most of your other questions, the TMS Web Core is just noise, because there is no distinction needed due to the tag. For more information, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/172661

@KenWhite I've had one or two questions where I didn't mention TMS WEB Core in the title initially and then people didn't realize it was for TMS WEB Core even though it had the tag. So they answered and commented things that weren't relevant to TMS WEB Core at all. So it's not really for SEO, but rather for the users so that they realize it's related to TMS WEB Core projects.

The tags do that, and if people comment because they miss them, you should point them to the tags. It's not OK to add noise to your post title to appease a few people who haven't learned how the site works yet. Did you read the link I provided? Also, [ask] mentions that adding tags to the title should be something rare, not normal - it's typically done when you're referencing a specific version of something where a tag for that version has not yet been created (like a tag for Delphi 13.1, when Delphi 12.1 is the most recent available), and should last only until the tag appears.

I ended up finding a WEBLib.Diagnostics unit in the "Core Source" folder for TMS WEB Core that has a TStopwatch record in it.
So if you want to use the TStopwatch in TMS WEB Core using Delphi, then you need to include the WEBLib.Diagnostics unit into your uses list instead of System.Diagnostics.
